# How to disable gray "wipe" effect when clicking mat-menu-item

Tags: css, angular

I've got a mat-nav-list with mat-menu-items within.  I've setup a routerLinkActive class in my scss to change the background and color of the text of the mat-menu-item when an item is clicked.  However, when one of the items is clicked, it changes it background to a light gray and my background-color is only shown after you click elsewhere within the application.

The behavior is visible in the below gif.

[image: Behavior of Mat-Menu-Item on click]

I'd like for the mat-menu-item background-color to change to my chosen chosen color without the default "gray wipe" behavior, is this possible?

My code is below if required:

**app.html**

```
<mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" [opened]="(sideNavOpened)" class="sidenav-inner-content">
    <mat-nav-list>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink="/customers/search" routerLinkActive="active"><mat-icon>search</mat-icon> Search Customer</a>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink="/customers/create" routerLinkActive="active"><mat-icon>add</mat-icon> Create Customer</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
</mat-sidenav>
```

**app.scss**

```
.active {
    border-left: 5px solid mat-color($accent);
    background-color: mat-color($primary);
    color: $light-primary-text !important;
}
```

Comment: From a quick look at the docs https://material.angular.io/components/menu/api there are three interesting `@Input()` that you might leverage to override the 'gray swipe' effect - have you tried defining `backdropClass`, `hasBackdrop` or `panelClass`?

Comment: Are you sure that this `background-color: mat-color($primary);` is correct? Try only `background-color: $primary;` if you have some color in primary variable. Also you can disable pointer events with `pointer-events: none` in CSS. If you can post link from this example on stackblitz please.

Comment: @N.Tasikj mat-color($primary) is correct.  As you can see, it does update the color of my element, but it's not visible due to the mat-menu-item wipe being overlayed.

Comment: Aha yea, try it with making background-color !important, working for me

Comment: @N.Tasikj ah-ha, so simple, can't believe I missed that.  Feel free to make an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put !important after your background-color css to override mat's background color.

```
.active {
    border-left: 5px solid mat-color($accent);
    background-color: mat-color($primary) !important;
    color: $light-primary-text !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise against using `!important` wherever possible. With a view-encapsulated framework like Angular, it's almost never required to override CSS options. Plus, with overriding the ink effect's styles, the ripple and behavior is still there, just invisible--it's still a semi-expensive animation, both with resources and time taken to complete.

Instead, the `MatList`, `MatOption`, and `MatNavList` API has a native option called [disableRipple](https://material.angular.io/components/list/api) to get rid of the ink effect.

```
<mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" [opened]="(sideNavOpened)" class="sidenav-inner-content">
    <mat-nav-list [disableRipple]="true">
        <a mat-list-item routerLink="/customers/search" routerLinkActive="active"><mat-icon>search</mat-icon> Search Customer</a>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink="/customers/create" routerLinkActive="active"><mat-icon>add</mat-icon> Create Customer</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
</mat-sidenav>
```

You can also use `disableRipple` selectively on each `mat-list-item`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this only applies to the animation effect, not the color overlay. The ripple effect is fine, but it was the color change that derailed my intended outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The shadow is caused by 'mat-list-item-ripple' and 'mat-ripple'. I know of two solutions:

1) Add the following to your styles.css:

```
.mat-nav-list .mat-list-item .mat-list-item-ripple {
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

2) Or add the following to the .css of the page in question:

```
::ng-deep .mat-nav-list .mat-list-item .mat-list-item-ripple {
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
```